# Sorting a table in React error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application that loads up sizes and stock quantities for particular items, based on user input. Right now, I have two tables loading for each product, one for out of stock items and their sizes and one for in stock items and their sizes. I would like to be able to sort the In Stock table ascending/descending based on the quantity each size has.

So this picture below kinda shows the output as I have it right now. Two tables, one of them should have sorting capabilities.

[image]

My approach to this was to create an InStockTable component, where the sorting logic occurs. I'm using this codepen for reference. The difference between that one and mine is that I'm passing the table data as props to the component, rather than having it hardcoded in the component state.

This is the code for the component that handles each product:

```
class Product extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    renderRow(row) { // this function is for the rows of the out of stock table. These need not to be sorted.
        return (
            <tr key="row.size_id">
               <td>{row.quantity}</td>
               <td>{row.size_text}</td>
            </tr>
        );
     }

     renderSortableRow(row) { // this is for the rows that need to be sorted
        var row = {
            "quantity": row.quantity,
            "size": row.size_text
        }

        return row;
     }

     renderProductDetails(product) {
        const inStockProdStr = [];
        const outStockProdStr = [];

        if (product.length) { // product is an array
            product.forEach(p => {
                if (p.quantity == 0) {
                    outStockProdStr.push(this.renderRow(p))
                }
                else {
                    inStockProdStr.push(this.renderSortableRow(p))
                }
            });
        }
        else { // product is an object
            if (typeof product == 'object') {
                Object.keys(product).forEach(id => {
                    if (product[id].quantity == '0') {
                        outStockProdStr.push(this.renderRow(product[id]))
                    }
                    else {
                   inStockProdStr.push(this.renderSortableRow(product[id]))
                    }
                }
                );
            }
        }

        return (
            <div className={'product-tables'}>
                <InStockTable stockArr={inStockProdStr} />
                <div className={'out-stock'}>
                    <h5>Out Of stock</h5>
                    <table className={'table'}>
                        <thead className="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Qty</th>
                                <th scope="col">Size</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {outStockProdStr.map(p => p)}
                        </tbody>
                   </table>
                </div>
            </div >
        );
    }

render() {
    return (
        <div id="product-container">
            <div id="product-info">
                <h2>{this.props.productId}</h2>
                <div id="product-line-detail">
                    {
                        this.renderProductDetails(this.props.prodStock)
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

This is the code for the In Stock table component:

```
class InStockTable extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className={'in-stock'}>
            <h5>In stock</h5>
            <table className={'table'}>
                <thead className="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Qty</th>
                        <th scope="col">Size</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        this.props.stockArr.map((s) => (
                            <tr key={s.simple_id}>
                                <td>{s.quantity}</td>
                                <td>{s.size_text}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

If all this worked, I should be able to create a sorting function inside the inStock table component. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {quantity, size}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in tbody (created by Product)
    in table (created by Product)
    in div (created by Product)
    in div (created by Product)
    in div (created by Product)
    in div (created by Product)
    in div (created by Product)
    in Product (created by ProductList)
    in ProductList (created by RequestForm)
    in div (created by RequestForm)
    in div (created by RequestForm)
    in RequestForm
react-dom.development.js:59:15
The above error occurred in the <tbody> component:
    in tbody (created by Product)
    in table (created by Product)
    in div (created by Product)
    in div (created by Product)
    in div (created by Product)
    in div (created by Product)
    in div (created by Product)
    in Product (created by ProductList)
    in ProductList (created by RequestForm)
    in div (created by RequestForm)
    in div (created by RequestForm)
    in RequestForm
```

Any ideas? Is this the right way to sort?

Answer (score 0):

The error just means that you are trying to render an object, as the `p` in `{inStockProdStr.map(p => p)}` is

```
{
  "quantity": row.quantity,
  "size": row.size_text
}
```

Change it to similar to what you did below (change `{` to `(` so that the map function is actually returning the element):

```
{inStockProdStr.map((p) => (
  <tr>
    <td>{p.quantity}</td>
    <td>{p.size}</td>
  </tr>
))}
```

Comment: The error definitely is in this part. When I tried your solution my editor tells me the semicolon doesn't go there. Tried it with and without the semicolon and I still get the same error message.

Comment: Right, the semicolon shouldn't be there. Try my updated code. Need to put `}` right after `)` otherwise semicolon will still be inserted automatically by the browser.

Comment: Tried and not working :/ I changed my code above to reflect your changes. I also added a key just in case.

Comment: What's the error message? And are you sure that's still the place where you are getting the error? (try remove the code and see if you get a different error)

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake here. I was trying to display my InStockArr object in the OutStockArray area. The code now acts as expected and I've fixed the top to reflect.